# Samsung S-Pen SDK - Selecting All User Input Strokes Programmatically

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile-sdk, stylus-pen

Using the official sample app  :
http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pen
and specifically in the demo example *PenSample5_6_TextRecognition*..
There are two tools; brush to draw strokes and selection tool. The example lets you draw strokes on ***SpenSurfaceView*** and then lets you select whatever you want to recognize text..
After selection, ***SpenSurfaceView.ControlListener*** delegate fires the event :

> *public boolean onCreated(ArrayList selectedList,
>    ArrayList arg1,
>                    ArrayList arg2, ArrayList arg3, int arg4, PointF arg5)*

which sends ***selectedList*** as a list of selected strokes to the text recognition engine.

My question is : how to programmatically select all the strokes drawn on the canvas or the **SpenSurfaceView** without the user manually selection and without firing the event of selection to return selected strokes..
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick turned out to use the ***SpenPageDoc*** attached to the SpenSurfaceView to get all the drawn strokes

> ArrayList < SpenObjectBase> inputList= mSpenPageDoc.getObjectList(SpenObjectBase.TYPE_STROKE);